# Why is the "First time here?" banner on the Login Page?

Tags: discussion, new-users, login

I don't know if there's a valid reason for it, but something which's been bugging me lately is the fact that the "First Time Here? Check the FAQ!" bar appears at the top of the login page. Can we get rid of this? Is it just on every page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because login is also "account creation" for SO (et al). Therefore, it is the only chance to point new users in the direction of FAQ, which I believe is a meaningful and good thing to do.